Skolemization in Marker's Proof of Theorem 2.3.7 (Downward Löwenheim-Skolem)
For convenience, I'll re-state Lemma 2.3.6 and Theorem 2.3.7 in Marker's Model Theory:

$\textbf{Lemma 2.3.6}$: Let $T$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-theory. There are $\mathcal{L}^\ast \supseteq \mathcal{L}$ and $T^\ast \supseteq T$ an $\mathcal{L}^\ast$ theory such that $T^\ast$ has built-in Skolem functions, and if $\mathcal{M} \models T$, then we can expand $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{M}^\ast \models T^\ast$. We can choose $\mathcal{L}^\ast$ such that $\vert \mathcal{L}^\ast \vert = \vert \mathcal{L} \vert + \aleph_0$. We call $T^\ast$ a skolemization of $T$.


$\textbf{Theorem 2.3.7 (L}\overset{..}{\textbf{o}}\textbf{wenheim-Skolem Theorem)}$: Suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-structure and $X \subseteq M$, there is an elementary submodel $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $X \subseteq N$ and $\vert \mathcal{N} \vert \le \vert X \vert + \vert \mathcal{L} \vert + \aleph_0$.

Now for the question:
The proof of Theorem 2.3.7 starts by stating that "by Lemma 2.3.6, we may assume that Th($\mathcal{M}$) has built-in Skolem functions." But can we guarantee this? Th($\mathcal{M}$) is an $\mathcal{L}$-theory (as $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-structure), so we have no way of guaranteeing that it has built-in Skolem functions; it's entirely possible we have to include more function symbols in our language. Perhaps this is what Marker meant: we extend Th($\mathcal{M}$) to its skolemization via Lemma 2.3.6, obtaining a new theory with an expanded language of size $\vert \mathcal{L} \vert + \aleph_0$. This is consistent with the size claim at the end of Theorem 2.3.7.
Does this construction work, or does Th($\mathcal{M}$) already have built-in Skolem functions?

I haven't read the details of Marker's argument, but "we may assume" almost certainly means we may assume without loss of generality.


Yes, the idea is that we Skolemize the theory, expand a model to a model of the Skolemized theory, produce an elementary submodel as a Skolem hull, and then show that the reduct to the original language is an elementary submodel of the original model satisfying the desired properties.
I think it's better/more natural to include nullary functions (or equivalently constant symbols) as witnesses to formulas with no additional variables. But I don't know that it presents a real issue because you get them for free, essentially, when the dependence of a formula on the other variables is trivial. (Edit: I think this actually doesn't quite patch up the problem when we're taking the Skolem hull of the empty set, though to prove the theorem for $X=\emptyset$ we can just start with an arbitrary singleton rather than the empty set in that case and be fine.)


Thanks for your answer! Towards 2: I see how the original idea of including nullary functions as witnesses works for formulae with one free variable, but how else would we get a Skolem function for free if the dependence of a formula on the other variables is trivial? I.e., wouldn't we be forced to interpret and include a nullary function/constant in our language according to the definition of a theory having built-in Skolem functions?

@DZvig If we have some formula $\varphi(x)$ with one free variable, that's effectively equivalent to, say $\varphi'(x,y) := \varphi(x)\land y=y$ (or just to $\varphi'(x,y):=\varphi(x)$ if we don't require the variable to actually appear), and then a Skolem function $f_{\varphi'}(y)$ will produce a witness to $\exists x\varphi(x)$ if there are any... maybe different witnesses for each $y$ but that doesn't matter.

@DZvig Eh, actually, that's still a bit problematic if we're taking the Skolem Hull of the empty set. Best to just do it right.

Does the equivalence of $\varphi^\prime (x, y)$ and $\varphi(x)$ happen on the level of semantics? It seems that with the way Marker has set up his syntax, the interpretation of a Skolem function that witnesses $\varphi(x)$ would be nullary (or, a constant), but for $\varphi^\prime (x, y)$, it has to be a unary function. Specifically, doesn't the notation for $\varphi^\prime (x, y)$ require $y$ to appear (as free)?

Also, keeping in line with how this question was closed for not being focused, should I create a new question addressing this point and we can continue there?

@DZvig I'm not sure why this was closed... I guess they're really cracking down on posts with multiple questions? It's a bit irritating since the questions were sufficiently compact and related in my opinion, and there was already my accepted, not overlong answer addressing the questions as they were, and now it looks strange now that you've edited in response. The closure doesn't mean we're obligated to stop discussing in the comments here... it just means there can't be any new answers added (and may result in eventual deletion of the question).

@DZvig It may require it to appear, it may not... it doesn't really matter, as even if it does require that, $\varphi(x)\land y=y$ does have $y$ free, and the Skolem function for that produces witnesses for $\varphi(x).$ (They are equivalent in the sense that a Skolem function/constant for one produces witnesses to the same thing as a Skolem function/constant for the other.) The problem, as I mentioned, is we run into difficulty with "the substructure generated by the empty set" when we try to replicate the constants with unary functions that produce the same witnesses.

@DZvig (The 'substructure generated by the emptyset' is a notion that's made unnecessarily subtle when you don't allow the empty structure. But when there are constant symbols in the language, it makes sense either way. Marker doesn't mention this notion explicitly in the proof, instead doing a closure under (1-ary and above) Skolem functions, which is wrong when $X=\emptyset$ no matter how you slice it, though as I mention this can be easily fixed for the sake of this proof by just initially seeding $X$ with some element.)

Ah! I think I see what you mean. My confusion was on the seemingly strict form of $f(\bar{w})$ as a witness for some $\varphi(v, \bar{w})$;  as long we can find some Skolem function that works just as well. I was picturing the map between formulae and their Skolem functions as injective when it seems it doesn't have to be.

@DZvig What you really need is at the end of the day is a way to make every existential sentence with parameters in the submodel that is witnessed in the model be witnessed in the submodel (i.e. the Tarski-Vaught test passes). This doesn't even really need expansion of the language to accomplish, it just seems a good place to introduce Skolemization which will be needed later (e.g. for Ehrenfeucht–Mostowski models). You can just iterate, starting with $N_0=X,$ adding a witness for each existential sentence over $N_0$ to get $N_1$, and so on for $N_1,N_2,\ldots$ and let $N= \bigcup_n N_n$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

We can understand Marker's proof of the theorem through the spirit of lemma 2.3.6; namely, that we want to add witnesses to existential statements into the universe of $\mathcal{N}$. We do not need to expand the language and construct a Skolemization.
Formally, let $X_0 = X \cup \{c^{\mathcal{M}} \in M : c \in \mathcal{C}\}$. Given $X_i$, let
$$X_{i+1} = X_i \cup \{m \in M : \text{if } \bar{x} \in X_i^n \text{ and } \mathcal{M} \models \exists v \, . \, \varphi(v, \bar{x}), \, m \text{ is a witness to } \exists v \, . \, \varphi(v, \bar{x})\}.$$
Note that we can use a choice function to pick only one $m$ per sentence, getting us the required cardinality. Let $N = \bigcup X_i$.
We want to ensure $\mathcal{N}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{M}$.

Suppose $f$ is an n-ary function symbol of $\mathcal{L}$ and $\bar{x} \in N^n$. Then $\bar{x} \in X_i^n$ for some $i$, and so we have a witness $y \in X_{i+1}$ for the sentence $\exists v \, . \, v = f(\bar{x})$. Letting $f^{\mathcal{N}}(\bar{x}) = y$, we have $f^{\mathcal{N}} : N^n \to N$.

Suppose $R$ is an n-ary relation symbol of $\mathcal{L}$. Let $R^{\mathcal{N}} = R^{\mathcal{M}} \cap N^n$.

Suppose $c$ is a constant symbol of $\mathcal{L}$. By construction, $c^{\mathcal{M}} \in N$. So let $c^{\mathcal N} = c^{\mathcal M}$.


It is easy to verify that $\mathcal{N}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{M}$. By Tarski-Vaught, $\mathcal{N} \prec \mathcal{M}$.
This proof is inspired by helpful conversations with @spaceisdarkgreen and by Corollary 2.1.3 in [1], which follows a similar approach.
[1] Tent, Katrin; Ziegler, Martin, A course in model theory, Lecture Notes in Logic 40. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press; Ithaca, NY: Association of Symbolic Logic (ASL) (ISBN 978-0-521-76324-0/hbk). x, 248 p. (2012). ZBL1245.03002.
